# Jena 3 and DAML

Tags: jena

I wanted to create a Model from a DAML file. I understand that in jena 2 there was a package called `com.hp.hpl.jena.daml` which helped in reading DAML files. However I can't find the equivalent in jena 3. Is there a way to read a DAML file in jena 3?

Comment: DAML is a defunct language that has been superseded by the OWL language.  Therefore there is no support for DAML in Jena 3 AFAIK